# How to access a variable present in state in cubit in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cubit

I am using cubit for state management in my app. I have a variable in the state called `prices` which I want to access:

```
Future<void> fetchMonthlyTotals(String userId) async {
    //var userId = await getUserId();
    var prices =
        await myDB().getPrices(userId);
    print(prices .toString());
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (prices != null && prices .isNotEmpty) {
      emit(MonthlyTotalsState(monthlyTotals: prices ));
    } else {
      debugPrint("prices is empty");
    }
  }
```

This is the class where I want to access `prices` variable:

```
void getExpenses() async {
    var prices = //get price from cubit
    print(prices);
}
```

Both the codes are in different classes and are present in the same package

How do I access the `price` variable?

Kindly comment if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use this value inside the UI you should use a `BlocBuilder`.
It will update your UI whenever the state changes.
If you however want to do something like showing a dialog or navigating in response to a state change you should use a `BlocListener`. If you want to do a combination of both of the mentioned use-cases you can use a `BlocConsumer`

```dart
BlocBuilder<ReportinCubit, MonthlyTotalsState>(
        builder: (_, monthlyTotalState) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('Monthly Total Prices: ${monthlyTotalState.prices}'),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: What is `ReportinCubit`?

Comment: Nothing more than the name of the cubit, you are using, whose state you want to have access to

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this aswell

```
BlocBuilder<Cubit, CubitState>(
  buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is MonthlyTotalsState     
    builder: (context, state) {
      if(state is MonthlyTotalsState){
       return Center(
         child: Text('Monthly TotalPrices:${state.monthlyTotals}'),
         );
       }
       return const SizedBox();
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use this value inside the UI you should use a `CubitBuilder`.
It will update your UI whenever the state changes.

```dart
CubitBuilder<ReportinCubit, MonthlyTotalsState>(
        builder: (_, monthlyTotalState) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('Monthly Total Prices: ${monthlyTotalState.prices}'),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: `CubitBuilder` is not getting recognized

Comment: You can use `BlocBuilder` instead, that's what I always use, didn't even know there was a `CubitBuilder`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. `CubitBuilder` is now deprecated (for a long time). Now everything can be handled with a `BlocBuilder` :)